# Formatter not finishing file

Tags: java, file, formatting

This is a portion of my code (in a Runnable class) where my file is made. It should be printing 1997 lines of data but instead it's only writing about 1 thousand lines.
This code is not returning any exception errors so I do not know what could be causing this glitch. I also tried making this part of the Main class which has the same problem.  One thing hinting out to to why this is happening is the file reaches 8 kb of data but I'm not sure. But if you know of a way to fix this problem please tell ne because I have no idea how to get this to work the way I want to.

```
Main ma=new Main();

/*most variables were taken from the main class

These variables are:
ma (Main class object )(created so I can call variables from the Main Class)
ma.scrn (Main class int=0)
ma.save (Main class Formatter)
ma.used (Main class ArrayList <String>)

*/
    while(ma.scrn<1996){
Formatter save=ma.save;
save.format("%d", ma.scrn+1);
save.format("%s", " ");                                    
save.format("%s",ma.used.get(ma.scrn));


save.format("%s","\r\n"); 


        ma.scrn+=1;

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);

    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.

Comment: Please show a complete example. You just showed what are you formatting. Show where you are printing to file.

Comment: I am not reprinting out the file, I am simply writing the file to be viewed as a text document later

Comment: Do you want the complete code